# add something to nametuple

Tags: python

I build

```
Corpus = collections.namedtuple('Corpus', 'a, b, c, d')
```

Read all the files in the corpus and save the data,

```
def compute(counters, tokens, catergory)
    ...
    counters.stats[tokens][catergory] = Corpus(a, b, c, d)
```

Both tokens and catergory are collection.Counter(). After reading all the information in a, b, c, d in counters.stats, I do some calculation in another function and get 'e' for each token. How can I add e into counters.stats in this function?

Comment: `<pedant>`It's [category](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/category), not catergory. `</pedant>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about adding 'e' to the Corpus namedtuple of `counter.stats[tokens][category]`then that is not possible as namedtuples are immutable. You may have to create a new namedtuple with the `a b c d e` values and assign it to counter.stats[tokens][category]. The code below is an example:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> two_d = namedtuple('twoDPoint', ['x', 'y'])
>>> x = two_d(1, 2)
>>> x = two_d(1, 2)
>>> three_d = namedtuple('threeDPoint', ['x', 'y', 'z'])
>>> x
twoDPoint(x=1, y=2)
>>> y = three_d(*x, z=3)
>>> y
threeDPoint(x=1, y=2, z=3)
```